# Argument of type 'Object[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Place[] | PromiseLike<Place[]>'

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

Hello folks!

I am coding an app with ionic and have a problem with this. I have implemented this code in the project for another page(places.html and places.ts), but I want to implement for the page and I get the error.

The problem in the bottom line and this line on "data".

```
query.find().then(data => resolve(data), error => reject(error));

resolve(data);
```

Can you help me?

All Code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import Parse from 'parse';

@Injectable()
export class Place extends Parse.Object {

constructor() {
 super('Place');
}

distance(location, unit) {

if (!location) {
  return null;
}

var geoPoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({
  latitude: location.latitude,
  longitude: location.longitude
});

if (unit === 'km') {
  return this.location.kilometersTo(geoPoint).toFixed(2) + ' ' + unit;
 } else {
  return this.location.milesTo(geoPoint).toFixed(2) + ' ' + unit;
 }
}

static like(place) {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  Parse.Cloud.run('likePlace', { placeId: place.id }).then(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, error => {
    reject(error);
  });
 });
 }

 static load(params): Promise<Place[]> {

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let page = params.page || 0;
  let limit = params.limit || 50;
  let distance = params.distance || 100;

  let query = new Parse.Query(this);
  var subQuery = new Parse.Query(this);
  var subQueryTwo = new Parse.Query(this);

  subQuery.greaterThan('expiresAt', new Date());
  subQueryTwo.doesNotExist('expiresAt');

  query = Parse.Query.or(subQuery, subQueryTwo);
  query.include('category');
  query.equalTo('isApproved', true);

  if (params.category) {
    query.equalTo('category', params.category);
  }

  if (params.search && params.search !== '') {
    query.contains('canonical', params.search);
  }

  if (params.location) {

    var point = new Parse.GeoPoint({
      latitude: params.location.latitude,
      longitude: params.location.longitude
    });

    if (params.unit && params.unit === 'km') {
      query.withinKilometers('location', point, distance);
    } else {
      query.withinMiles('location', point, distance);
    }
  } else {
    query.descending('createdAt');
  }

  query.skip(page * limit);
  query.limit(limit);

  query.find().then(data => resolve(data), error => reject(error));
});
}

static loadFavorites(params): Promise<Place[]> {

 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let page = params.page || 0;
  let limit = params.limit || 50;

  let query = new Parse.Query(this);
  query.equalTo('isApproved', true);
  query.equalTo('likes', Parse.User.current());

  query.skip(page * limit);
  query.limit(limit);

  query.find().then(data => resolve(data), error => reject(error));
});
}

static create(data): Promise<Place> {

return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

  let place = new Parse.Object('Place');

  place.save(data).then(data => {
    resolve(data);
  }, error => {
    reject(error);
  });
});
}

get title(): string {
 return this.get('title');
}

set title(val) {
  this.set('title', val);
}

get description(): string {
 return this.get('description');
}

set description(val) {
 this.set('description', val);
}

get phone(): string {
 return this.get('phone');
}

 set phone(val) {
 this.set('phone', val);
}

get website(): string {
  return this.get('website');
}

set website(val) {
  this.set('website', val);
}

get address(): string {
  return this.get('address');
}

set address(val) {
  this.set('address', val);
}

get category() {
  return this.get('category');
}

set category(val) {
  this.set('category', val);
}

get image() {
  return this.get('image');
}

set image(val) {
  this.set('image', val);
}

get location() {
  return this.get('location');
}

set location(val) {
  var geoPoint = new Parse.GeoPoint({
  latitude: val.lat,
  longitude: val.lng
});
this.set('location', geoPoint);
}

get imageTwo() {
  return this.get('imageTwo');
}

get imageThree() {
  return this.get('imageThree');
}

get imageFour() {
  return this.get('imageFour');
}

get imageThumb() {
  return this.get('imageThumb');
}

get ratingCount() {
  return this.get('ratingCount');
}

get ratingTotal() {
  return this.get('ratingTotal');
}

get rating() {

 if (!this.ratingCount && !this.ratingTotal) {
  return null;
}

return Math.round(this.ratingTotal / this.ratingCount);
}

}

Parse.Object.registerSubclass('Place', Place);
```

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJyqh.png)

Comment: can you postt the  code here .. very difficult to guess the error from screenshot

Comment: post the code for `query.find()`  where you are calling `resolve()` in the promise.

Comment: I edited the question with adding all code. query is a Parse.Query and this code block is running a different page.

Comment: can you try with `query.find({
    success: obj: Place[] => {
        console.log(obj);
    },
    error: error => {
        console.log(error);
    }
}).then(data => resolve(data), error => reject(error));`

Comment: else you can change the return type of the `load` method to `Promise<any[]>`

Comment: refer this link http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.0/Parse.Query.html#find

Comment: I solved it. Thank you.

Comment: great .. what was the issue?

Comment: When I write Promise<any[]>, the red underline disappeared.